# Django control looping

Tags: django

How do I control the loop?

for example if the user choose the "13" in Number Of Grades, it will show 13 search result , just like in the picture below

[image]

and if the user choose for example, "2" Number of grades it will show like this

[image]

and if the user choose "3" Number Of Grades it will show like this
[image]

this is my views.py

```
def gradescales(request):
    grade = gradeScalesSetting.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'Homepage/gradescale.html',{"gradeScalesSetting":grade})
def gradescaleview(request):
    id = request.GET.get('gradescale')
    grade = gradescale.objects.all().filter(Grade_Scales_Setting__id=id)
    return render(request, 'Homepage/gradescaleview.html', {'gradescale': grade})
```

this is my models.py

```
class gradeScalesSetting(models.Model):
    Configuration = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    NumberOfGrades = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Rounding = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    Precision = models.FloatField()


class gradescale(models.Model):
    Grade_Scales_Setting = models.ForeignKey(gradeScalesSetting, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Display_Sequence = models.IntegerField()
    Symbol = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    LowerLimit = models.FloatField()
    GPAValue = models.FloatField()
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, choices=Pending_Request, blank=True)
```

please help me, tomorrow is the deadline for this assignment.

**UPDATE**
this is my javascript on searching data

```
<button class="accordion"><b>Percents Only</b>
<p>Standard grade scale that does not convert grades to symbols</p>
</button>

<div class="panel">
    <p><b>Name:</b> Percents Only</p>
    <p><b>Description:</b> Standard grade scale that does not convert grades to symbols</p>
    <table width="50%">
    <tr>
        <th>Configuration</th>
        <th>Number Of Grades</th>
        <th>Rounding</th>
        <th>Precision</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
                <select  name="summary" id="summary" onchange="summary(this.value)" required="required" >
                    <option>--</option>
                {% for grade in gradeScalesSetting %}
                            <option value="{{grade.id}}" name="schoolyear">{{grade.Configuration}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </td>
                <td>
                <select  name="count" id="count"  required="required">
                    <option>all</option>
                {% for grade in gradeScalesSetting %}
                            <option value="{{grade.NumberOfGrades}}" name="num">{{grade.NumberOfGrades}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </td>
                <td>
                <select  name="schoolyear" required="required">
                {% for grade in gradeScalesSetting %}
                            <option value="{{grade.id}}" name="schoolyear">{{grade.Rounding}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </td>
                <td >
                <select  name="schoolyear" required="required">
                    <option>all</option>
                {% for grade in gradeScalesSetting %}
                            <option value="{{grade.id}}" name="schoolyear">{{grade.Precision}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr >
            <td width="50%" ><div id="txtHint"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<script>
function summary(str) {
var xhttp;
if (str == "") {
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
return;
}
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "{% url 'gradescaleview' %}?gradescale="+str, true);
xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

when i tried this in my javascript

```
**xhttp.open("GET", "{% url 'gradescaleview' %}?gradescale="+str+"&count="+count, true);**
```

my views.py

```
count = request.GET.get('count')
grade = gradescale.objects.all().filter(Grade_Scales_Setting__id=id)[:count]
```

my error is

```
Internal Server Error: /gradescaleview/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\SchoolWebsite-Project\SchoolWebsite-Project1\Homepage\views.py", line 22, in gradescaleview
    grade = gradescale.objects.all().filter(Grade_Scales_Setting__id=id)[:count]
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 287, in __getitem__
    (k.stop is None or k.stop >= 0))), \
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
[26/Nov/2019 12:30:05] "GET /gradescaleview/?gradescale=2&count=1 HTTP/1.1" 500 77319
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You limit the query results returned with slicing.

```
gradescale.objects.all().filter(Grade_Scales_Setting__id=id)[:13]
gradeScalesSetting.objects.all()[:13]
```

That would return the first 13 objects in the queryset

To return the last 13 objects you would do:

```
gradescale.objects.all().filter(Grade_Scales_Setting__id=id)[-13:]
gradeScalesSetting.objects.all()[-13:]
```

Just like you are sending `gradescale="+str` param in the GET request below

```
xhttp.open("GET", "{% url 'gradescaleview' %}?gradescale="+str, true);
xhttp.send();
```

and retrieving it in the backend with:

```
id = request.GET.get('gradescale')
```

You need to add a second URL parameter for `count`

```
xhttp.open("GET", "{% url 'gradescaleview' %}?gradescale=+str?count=count, true);
```

And then get that url parameter variable `count` in the back end like so:

```
count = request.GET.get('count')
grade = gradescale.objects.all().filter(Grade_Scales_Setting__id=id)[:count]
```

You will also need to modify your url in `urls.py` to include this new param.

Comment: that 13 is dynamic? or static? how about if the user choose number 3 in Number Of Grading Period

Comment: You pass that number in the post/get data of your form and set it dynamically

Comment: This is how it is done. Saying no results happen does not give me any clue of what exact problem you faced and at what step. I can only give you a broader direction. Coding it will take effort and time

Comment: I get your point sir, its up to me now on how to run this solutions, Thanks :)

Comment: you need to convert count from string to int like. `count = int(request.GET.get('count'))`